# OpenLayers 3 clusters optimization - how to avoid calculating averages every time

Tags: javascript, openlayers-3

This is an example of code very similar to my real-life application:

```
var count = 20000;
var features = new Array(count);
var e = 4500000;
var pointStyle = new ol.style.Style({
  image: new ol.style.Circle({
    fill: new ol.style.Fill({color: "red"}),
    radius: 6,
    snapToPixel: true,
  }),
});
for (var i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
  var coordinates = [2 * e * Math.random() - e, 2 * e * Math.random() - e];
  features[i] = new ol.Feature({
    geometry: new ol.geom.Point(coordinates),
    labelPoint: new ol.geom.Point(coordinates),
    name: Math.random()
  });
  features[i].setStyle(pointStyle);
}

var source = new ol.source.Vector({
  features: features
});

var clusterSource = new ol.source.Cluster({
  distance: 40,
  source: source
});

var styleCache = {};
var clusters = new ol.layer.Vector({
  source: clusterSource,
  style: function(feature, resolution) {
      style = [new ol.style.Style({
        image: new ol.style.Circle({
          radius: 10,
          stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
            color: '#fff'
          }),
          fill: new ol.style.Fill({
            color: '#3399CC'
          })
        }),
        text: new ol.style.Text({
          text: avg(feature.get('features')),
          fill: new ol.style.Fill({
            color: '#fff'
          })
        })
      })];
    return style;
  }
});

var raster = new ol.layer.Tile({
  source: new ol.source.MapQuest({layer: 'sat'})
});

var raw = new ol.layer.Vector({
  source: source
});

var map = new ol.Map({
  layers: [raster, clusters],
  renderer: 'canvas',
  target: 'map',
  view: new ol.View({
    center: [0, 0],
    zoom: 2
  })
});

function avg(features){
  var temp = 0;
  features.forEach(function(val){
    temp += val.get('name')
  });
  temp = temp/features.length;
  return temp;
```

https://jsfiddle.net/wydo007p/

This is very similar to the code I have, except I have much bigger array of features. When you zoom in to maximum it works reasonably fast, but when you zoom out from max, it takes ages to recalculate all the averages.

I really need this to be more optimized and I'm slowly running out of ideas.

I assume I need something along [these](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.6.0/examples/cluster.html) lines, except I can't have size as idetificator, because not all clusters with same sizes will have same averages.

Comment: Did you find any work around to your problem? I'm having some serious performance issues with clustering and I don't see how it can be fixed...

Answer (score 1):

The style function is not a good place to do expensive calculations, because it is called very often (as you found out). It is better to calculate the averages only once, upon creation of the cluster feature. To do so, you can register a listener to the source's `featureadded` event:

```js
clusterSource.on('addfeature', function(e) {
  e.feature.set('avg', avg(e.feature.get('features')));
});
```

In the style function, you can create a static style:

```js
var style = new ol.style.Style({
  image: new ol.style.Circle({
    radius: 10,
    stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
      color: '#fff'
    }),
    fill: new ol.style.Fill({
      color: '#3399CC'
    })
  }),
  text: new ol.style.Text({
    text: '',
    fill: new ol.style.Fill({
      color: '#fff'
    })
  })
});
```

This style has an empty text (''), which we will set in the cluster layer's style function:

```js
style: function(feature, resolution) {
  var avg = feature.get('avg');
  style.getText().setText(avg);
  return style;
}
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/tr91j6Lr/4/